# Python: what do these list indexes mean?

Tags: python, numpy

I have seen this statement:

```
x[:, 0:4]
```

I'm a little confused by this.  Can anyone explain what it means in terms of indexes into a list?

Comment: I assume this is in the context of numpy? If so, I'd suggest tagging the question as numpy.

Comment: That syntax is specific to pandas/numpy dataframes.  It is not valid for general Python.

Comment: It's a *type error* with regard to lists, because `list.__getitem__` doesn't accept tuples as arguments.

Comment: @JohnGordon Not true. The syntax is perfectly valid, and is implemented by `x.__getitem__((slice(None, None, None), slice(0, 4, None))`. Whether `x.__getitem__` knows what to *do* with such a tuple entirely depends on the type of `x`. (Extended slice syntax was *introduced* at the request of the NumPy community, IIRC, but anyone can make use of it.)

Comment: (For example, I use a simple class definition like `class A: __getitem__ = lambda self, k: print(k)` to examine different uses of extended slice syntax gets translated to.)

Comment: @chepner I should have said _usage_, not _syntax_.  Forgive me.

Comment: @Nick, Duplicate questions don't need to be deleted, just closed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is commonly used in the NumPy library, which provides various stuff for arrays and matrices.

The : symbol in the first position indicates that all rows of the array should be included in the selection.

The 0:4 specifies the column range and means that columns with indices from 0 up to, but not including, 4 will be selected.

```py
x = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
     [6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
     [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]])
```

Using the x[:, 0:4] notation, the selected subset of elements would be:

```py
[[1, 2, 3, 4],
 [6, 7, 8, 9],
 [11, 12, 13, 14]]
```

Comment: `x` is a list; `x[:, 0:4]` will not produce the list shown.

Comment: You need to use `x = np.array(x)` before this will work without error.